# Plugin WordPress: basic hypertext link PHP

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, hyperlink

I'm beginning in PHP/WordPress development, and I am trying to build a little plugin.

In my administration page, I want to make a link so that people can click on it and go to another page, mypage.php for example.

I tried different things, like:

```
<a href="mypage.php">Click on my page</a>
```

And a few other variants, but still I get the same error, *404 page not found*. Maybe I could do it with a submenu_page, but I still don't know how to make the link with this kind of page.

My problem is probably very basic, but I have no idea how to solve it and I couldn't find an answer to my specific case, so how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you need to add a link in the WordPress admin menu at the backend for your plugin. Here is a very simple example to do this.

It will create a sub-level menu item under the Settings top-level menu, and when selected, that menu item will cause a very basic screen to display. Note: this code should be added to a main plugin PHP file or a separate PHP include file.

```
<?php
    /** Step 2 (from text above). */
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

    /** Step 1. */
    function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_options_page( 'My Plugin Options', 'My Plugin', 'manage_options', 'my-unique-identifier', 'my_plugin_options' );
    }

    /** Step 3. */
    function my_plugin_options() {
        if ( !current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) )  {
            wp_die( __( 'You do not have sufficient permissions to access this page.' ) );
        }
        echo '<div class="wrap">';
        echo '<p>Here is where the form would go if I actually had options.</p>';
        echo '</div>';
    }
?>
```

Please see the link https://codex.wordpress.org/Administration_Menus for more detailed information.

Comment: It's inside the plugin folder but your path looks to doesn't work. And this would add a blank page or a wordpress page ? because i want to make another wordpress page (that's why i was thinking about add_submenu_page or something like that).

Comment: Thank you a lot for your update, that's what i needed but what i need now is to make a link in my main page to this subpage. Do you know how i can make that ?

Comment: please show me a screenshot or something, so that i can look exactly what you need.

Comment: I can't add image yet (i'm new on this forum...). But what i would like is an hypertext link on my main admin page. And when i click on the link it opens a sub_page (for example the page you helped me to make). Hope I was clear.

Comment: please upload your screenshot image to http://postimg.org/ and share the link here.

Comment: thank for the image, now i clearly see what you need. In order to make that link work, you should create a submenu page using add_submenu_page() function, https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_submenu_page. I also have a good news, I have created a sample plugin for you that help you to know how to make that link work, if you like to download it, give me your email id, i will share it with you through dropbox.

Comment: @Gui I have share the link with you, once you install this plugin and activate it will create a Menu titled "Tarun Menu" at the WordPress admin, when you click on that menu, you will see a link, click on it and see your desired effect.

Comment: Thank you . I think it's what i need. I'll test and analyse it on Monday !

Comment: Dear @Gui , if this work for you, please share your views and mark this as a accepted answer of your question.

Comment: Yes it works exactly as i wanted ! Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

```
<a href="mypage.php"> click on my page </a>
```

This will only work if mypage.php is in the same directory as the page that the link is on.

If mypage.php is in a subfolder of the directory of the current page, you use:

```
<a href="subfolder/mypage.php"> click on my page </a>
```

If mypage.php is in a different directory, you will have to navigate to it.

```
<a href="../../superfolder/subfolder/mypage.php"> click on my page </a>
```

`../` means you go up one folder in the directory tree. So in this example you go up 2 folders, then go into superfolder, then go into subfolder, where mypage.php is located.

You can also make a root relative link, which is formatted as follows:

```
<a href ="/subfolder/mypage.php"> click on my page </a></a>
```

The leading slash means the root of your websites directory tree, or the top most folder. Then navigate down into a subfolder, where you find mypage.php.

Comment: Thanks for explanations but this doesn't work, despite the fact that the file is in the same directory. I assume it's because it's a wordpress plugin so it's a bit specific

Comment: What is the link of the page you are trying to get the link to display on, and what is the file you want to link to?

Comment: I want to link a wordpress administration page to another. (hope i understood your question)

Answer (score 0):

If your mypage.php is present within your website then try to do

```
<a href="/mypage.php/"> click on my page </a>
```

And if mypage.php is a page of another website then try to change your code to:

```
<a href="http://yourdomain.com/mypage.php/"> click on my page </a>
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations but this doesn't work, despite the fact that the file is in the same directory. I assume it's because it's a wordpress plugin so it's a bit specific

Answer (score 0):

The solution of my problem is to make a submenu page and to make a link to this submenu. I created a file myplugin.php and a file mypage.php in a folder myplugin. Here is the code to write in myplugin.php:

```
add_action('admin_menu','main_page');

function main_page(){
        add_menu_page('Plugin de test','Test','manage_options','test','sub_page');
    }

function sub_page(){
        ?>
        <h1> Ma page pour tester les liens <h1> </br> </br>
        <a href="admin.php?page=myplugin/mypage.php">Click here to see!!</a>&nbsp;
        <?php
    }
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'my_plugin_menu' );

function my_plugin_menu() {
        add_submenu_page(NULL, 'page title', 'menu title', 'read', 'myplugin/mypage.php' );
    }
```

Thank you all for your help, especially Tarun Mahashwari